# How to access a Protected Variable Correctly?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to access one of the protected variable from **items.h** class using **components.cpp**  class but I got the error confusing me: :D

> Item::Quantity': cannot access forbidden protected member declared in class
> 'Item'

**item.h**

```
 protected:
        int32 Quantity;
```

**component.h**

```
#include "Items/Item.h"
Item* AddItem(class Item* Item, const int32 Quantity);
```

**component.cpp**

```
ItemAddResult Component::TryAddItem_Internal(class Item* Item)
{
    Items.Add(Item);
    return ItemAddResult::AddedAll(Item->Quantity);
}
```

Comment: Quantity can't be accessed.

Comment: When asking questions where showing code is applicable, then please try to create a proper [mre] which replicates the issue you ask about and only that issue. If your code have other unrelated errors then they tend to distract from the actual issue you ask about. Please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good Suggestion thank you man, next I will be taking care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by making the class `Component` a `friend` of class `Item` by adding a **friend declaration** inside class `Item` as shown below:

**item.h**

```
class Item{
    friend class Component;
    protected: 
        int32 Quantity;
    //other members here
}
```